# .otf font is not used by windows service but by console application it is used

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, windows-services, ms-word

I have a windows-service which creates word mailmerge documents.

If any otf font is used in a mailmerge document the font is replaced in the resulting word doc (or pdf).

The windows-service is executed by a normal domain user.

When I run the program as a console application with the same user the font is used and the word document is created just normally.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I have now found out that the word document itself is saved correctly and the font is diplayed correctly. What I missed in my original description is that the Word Document is saved as as pdf file (by the built in word function).

In the resulting pdf the otf font is replaced by some System font.

I'm sorry that I missed that in my original description.

Hopefully you are still willing to help.

Comment: I don't really understand the setup you're describing here. Are you trying to run Word from a Windows Service? You know that this is not supported, right? Office doesn't run unattended, either a service or a web application. It requires an interactive desktop.

Comment: Is the problem only with otf fonts? You could list all fonts and see the difference - see [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209205/en-us).

Comment: @RomanPlischke yes only with otf fonts

Comment: @CodyGray yes word is run from a Windows Service and it works everything for years i know it is not recommended by Microsoft but this way it was done for years and in our case it just works fine. word (or Office) can be automated. that possibility is widely used...

Comment: Not just a solution, but a workaround: try install TrueType instead OTF. There are free conversion utilities, for example [here](http://www.freefontconverter.com/). Note: check font licence before the conversion.

Comment: @RomanPlischke mhh that does not work either... how can i check the license of a odt font? this particular one was sent to me by a customer who wants to use it in his mailmerge documents. they bought that font...

Comment: Every font is sold with licence agreement, which is usually deeper level of hell then program licence agreements. There is written, what you may do with font. However I wouldn't care, it is 99.9% legal in any case.

Comment: Is the Windows service running on a different machine than the Console application?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud no both run on the same machine under the same user account

Comment: is the font installed and available under that user under which the service is executed?

Comment: @DanielNachtrub mhh i copied the font to the Windows/Fonts dir with my own user account. do you think i should have used the user account under which the Service is executeed?

Comment: login with the service user and check if the font is available

Comment: @DanielNachtrub as i mentioned when i run the Service as a console app under the same user everything works fine

Comment: hm maybe when running in a context is missing some privileagues in the os. is it possible to run the program from Service in a hidden console (external program call). does it worker in such a Scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go about converting all otf fonts to ttf, you can do this through [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/).

How you go about doing the conversion depends on the platform, but here's the basic idea:

```
...
Open(filename);
Generate(filename:r+".ttf");
...
```

If the problem is really only with otf fonts, then converting them to ttf programatically should fix it for you.